# Get address for symbol in current process in Windows

Tags: windows, dll, shared-libraries, dylib

On *nix, you can compile a program with `-rdynamic` or loading dynamic libraries, use `dlopen(NULL, RTLD_NOW)` to get handle of current process, then use `dlsym()` with the handle to get address for a symbol within current process.

I am wondering what is the equivalent for doing so on Windows.

Comment: AFAIK, the main difference is that in Windows, the main executable doesn't have an export-table.

Comment: @ZsigmondLőrinczy the main executable can have an export table as well.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you can rely on [`LoadLibrary()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`GetProcAddress()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212(v=vs.85).aspx) APIs, both from `kernel32.dll`, to load a library and resolve its functions addresses. About `GetProcAddr()`:

> Retrieves the address of an exported function or variable from the
>   specified dynamic-link library (DLL).

and takes in parameter:

> A handle to the DLL module that contains the function or variable. The
>   LoadLibrary, LoadLibraryEx, LoadPackagedLibrary, or GetModuleHandle
>   function returns this handle.

If you want to resolve the adresses within the libraries of the process from an external process, your best bet would be to debug it with [`DebugActiveProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679295(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`ReadProcessMemory()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553(v=vs.85).aspx%60)

You will have to browse the PE Format structures from the base address of the process. Not trivial, but not that hard. This topic is closely related to code injection, but you might want to read [Understanding the Imports Address Table](http://sandsprite.com/CodeStuff/Understanding_imports.html)

Comment: `LoadLibrary()` seems to require a specified library name, and it loads the library and returns a handle to it. However, I hope to _not_ load any libraries, but instead, get a handle to current process (including the program and also loaded shared libraries) so that I can query address for symbols.

Comment: I added more details on this.

Comment: You can use `GetModuleHandle()` instead of `LoadLibrary()` if you want to look up the handle to an already loaded module.  You do need to know which module you want to get the symbol from; after all, multiple modules might declare the same symbol.  Incidentally, Fabien, the function is GetProcAddress() not GetProcAddr().

Comment: @HarryJohnston thanks. I happened to find `GetModuleHandle()` as well, however, it still requires me to know from which library/module the symbol is loaded. I am not sure what if I want the address of a symbol that is from the program itself (not any loaded library). I am wondering if it is possible.

Comment: @Harry I updated for GetProcAddress, as for the browse PE format job I said it was from a debugging perspective (outside process) by using the [debugging functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679303(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @qinsoon, to get a handle to the main module (aka the "program") call `GetModuleHandle(NULL)`.